# Cambiar el Skin de AdminLTE

Tags: html, css

Hola compañeros quisiera cambiar el skin de la Plantilla AdminLTE mediante un menu, con eso me refiero a que creo un menu donde aparecen los diferentes skins que trae y cuando de clic cambien sin necesidad de estar modificando la clase del css modificandolo cada vez desde:
Este sirve para el color negro claro

Aqui la llamada al css:

```
   <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/template/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

<body class="hold-transition skin-black-light sidebar-mini">
```

el menu quedaria en el header con algo asi:

```
<!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
<li>
     <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
     <li>Azul</li>
     <li>Negro</li>
</li>
</li>
```

Agregue esto y agregue el jQuery que me recomendaron, estara bien el html?

```
       <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
          <span class="label label-success">3</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="header">Seleccionar Tema</li>
          <li>
            <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><!-- start message -->
                <a href="#">
                  <div class="fa fa-circle">
                  <ul id="azul">Azul</ul>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <!-- end message -->
              <li><!-- start message -->
                <a href="#">
                  <div class="pull-left">
                  <ul id="negro">Black</ul>
                  </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="footer"><a href="#">Proximamente mas temas...</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Este es el body en donde esta la clase css de los skins:

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-black sidebar-mini">
<!-- Site wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" class="logo">
            <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
            <span class="logo-mini"><b>Q</b>C</span>
            <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
            <span class="logo-lg"><b>QC</b></span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
            <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
            <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
          <span class="label label-success">3</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="header">Seleccionar Tema</li>
          <li>
            <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><!-- start message -->
                <a href="#">
                  <div class="fa fa-circle" >
                  <ul id="azul">Azul</ul>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <!-- end message -->
              <li><!-- start message -->
                <a href="#">
                  <div class="pull-left">
                  <ul id="black">Negro</ul>
                  </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="footer"><a href="#">Proximamente mas temas...</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Aqui el JQuery

```
$('.azul').click(function(){
$('.body').removeClass('skin-black').addClass('skin-blue');});

$('.black').click(function(){$('.body').removeClass('skin-blue').addClass('skin-black');});
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el nombre de las clases de los elementos del menú "Azul" y "Negro"?

Comment: para ello usas jquery como ya te respondieron, tambien debes tomar en cuenta que para establecer un skin debes tener cargado x defecto dicho skin es decir cargar todos los skin en la pagina web, pudes usar el all-skins.min.css

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/template/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

Comment: Ya lo agregue y nada

Answer (score 1):

Con jQuery:

```
$('.azul').click(function(){
  $('body').removeClass('skin-black').addClass('skin-blue');
});

$('.black').click(function(){
  $('body').removeClass('skin-blue').addClass('skin-black');
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda amigo me sirvio de mucho

Comment: $(document).on("click",".btn-azul",function(){
      $('body').removeClass('skin-black').addClass('skin-blue');
    });

    $(document).on("click",".btn-negro",function(){
      $('body').removeClass('skin-blue').addClass('skin-black');
    });

Comment: Lo hice de esa manera pero no me funciona :(

Comment: El código JS que muestras esta bien, ahora comparte el HTML para revisarlo.

Comment: Lo comparti arriba

Comment: Excelente, ahora es más sencillo ubicar el problema, corrige los dos UL te falta agregar los LI con su respectiva clase. Ej: <ul id="azul"><li class="azul">Azul</li></ul>